# Varnish Edge Side Includes (ESI) supported on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, varnish, edge-side-includes

Anyone know if Edge Side Includes are supported by Heroku's Varnish implementation?

---

UPDATE:
I ended up putting in a support request to ask Heroku about their Varnish implementation. Here's my request:

> Hi, I was just wondering if your varnish implementation supports Edge Side Includes? Is there any information about what is and is not supported in your varnish implementation? (For example, I've read elsewhere that you can't PURGE entries?)

... and their response:

> We do not support ESI. We do, however, purge the varnish cache on each deploy. This will ensure that your static assets that are part of your code will be purged on any deploy so the cache will pickup any new or changed assets.
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> -Chris

Of course, by PURGE, I meant purging a route manually, which is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a while back and the answer was no. Could have changed though.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Just got the above response directly from Heroku.